# Video Card slot Question

Tags: motherboard, nvidia-geforce, pci-express

I am, most likely, getting [this](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-us.html) video card for my next computer build, the thing is: my motherboard only has one pci express 2.0 x16 slot the thing is this video card is dual slot

I don't know whether the video card will fit

since it's dual slot I am fearing that it will cover another needed port (not necessarily a PCIe slot)

does anyone know if it will fit

Comment: my probable motherboard can be found here: http://usa.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=HMMvTCuBcZLfu2YL it just wouldn't let me post more than one hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of fitting, what is important is your case, not your motherboard.  With some motherboards, especially older ones, a long, double-slot card would cover some SATA ports.  These days, most motherboards are careful to avoid that, either by moving the SATA ports around, or, as is the case on the P8P67 Pro that you linked to, the ports are pointed off to the side rather than straight up.  So unless you have a small case where the SATA ports (and edge of the motherboard in general) are too close to the drive bays, you should have no problems with any graphics card and that motherboard.

Comment: I would vote up if I had the required reputation

Answer (score 3):

It will fit, but you haven't told us what expansion cards you are/will be using, so we don't know if it will cover a needed slot.

Because it's a double height card, it will cover one other slot (below it), which from the motherboard you linked could be either a PCI or PCIe x1 slot.

Comment: Actually, it is obvious that the slot it would cover would be a PCIe x1 shot on the P6P67 Pro.

Comment: @farf, couldn't he also plug it into the white x16 slot instead?  The black one seems out because the specs say it shares a slot.

Comment: didn't think of that possibility.  The black one is indeed out, as not only does it share with the PCIe x1 slots (i.e.: no PLX bridge chip), but it has a mere x4 bandwidth despite having a x16 physical slot.  So while it _might_ work there, it would be kind of silly to put it there.  As for the white one, though, I _think_ that one would work just fine, but as you can see in my own question, I'm not 100% sure how the bandwidth splitting on the P67 motherboards work.

Comment: I am not using any of the other pcie slots so the card covering other PCI Express slots is not a fear

Comment: @farfromhome if it is, sorry...